# Easiest way to copy a dataview to a datatable in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable, dataview

I need to copy a dataview into a datatable. It seems like the only way to do so is to iterate through the dataview item by item and copy over to a datatable. There has to be a better way.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
dt = DataView.ToTable()
```

OR

`dt = DataView.Table.Copy()`,

OR

`dt = DataView.Table.Clone()`;

Comment: Thanks, google was failing me pretty badly. Hopefully this page will get ranked highly.

Comment: Note: `DataView.ToTable()` will only copy the values of the DataView. `DataView.Table.Copy()` will copy the source DataTable, not the filtered data of the DataView. `DataView.Table.Clone()` will only copy the structure of the source DataTable.

Answer (score 3):

The answer does not work for my situation because I have columns with expressions. `DataView.ToTable()` will only copy the values, not the expressions.

First I tried this:

```
//clone the source table
DataTable filtered = dt.Clone();

//fill the clone with the filtered rows
foreach (DataRowView drv in dt.DefaultView)
{
    filtered.Rows.Add(drv.Row.ItemArray);
}
dt = filtered;
```

but that solution was very slow, even for just 1000 rows.

The solution that worked for me is:

```
//create a DataTable from the filtered DataView
DataTable filtered = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();

//loop through the columns of the source table and copy the expression to the new table
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns) 
{
    if (dc.Expression != "")
    {
        filtered.Columns[dc.ColumnName].Expression = dc.Expression;
    }
}
dt = filtered;
```